# Upgrading mariadb on a running magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a running magento 1.9 webshop. (nginx, mariadb 5.5, php-fpm)

I'm thinking about upgrading mariadb 5.5 to mariadb 10.

Is there anything I should be prepared for?

I have a staging site where I will test the upgrade, but it's better to be informed first instead of going by trail and error.

**Edit:**

To be clear; This is a question about what effect the upgrade it would have on my running webshop. I need minimal downtime.

Comment: is there anything stops you from going to mariadb website and see all the changes???

Comment: This is not a question of what the changes are in mariadb, but what influence does it have on my running webshop.

Comment: nobody knows what you have there... your shop is not default magento demo website.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think this question can simply be answered checking this:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/system-requirements.html

Based on that Magento 1.x doesn't support MariaDB or another than:

> - MySQL 5.6
> - Oracle
> - Percona

So regarding your question:
**Is there anything I should be prepared for?**

I think that you should be prepared to anything, since Magento 1.x is not giving any information about how that can behave.

I was checking the same, and I've not found any relevant information related to Magento 1.x and MariaDB in the official documentation.